# cherrypy: server side code of getting image by http post and storing its path mysqldatabase

Tags: python, python-2.7, cherrypy, cherry-pick

m**cherrypy:python**y project is on iphone app...it require to manage profile of every user
i need to upload image and store its path in database.

im working on server side coding cherrypy framewok..i need to get image by http post and store its pathname in mysql database...

can u plz give me code and description how to fetch image by http post, how to prase image, and store in database....im new to cherrypy framework, first time im using this...plz help me

i tried cherrypy doc how to upload a file :: http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/files/uploading.html
but im unable to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get code working for the link you provided you'll need to add the line following my comment in the code below...

```
def upload(self, myFile):
    MySQLconnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['host'], 
                                 passwd=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['passwd'],
                                 db=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['db'],
                                 user=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['user'],
                                 port=cherrypy.request.app.config['Database']['port'], 
                                 cursorclass=DictCursor)
    MySQLcursor = MySQLconnection.cursor()
    size = 0

    # add this line
    all_data = bytearray()

    while True:
        data = myFile.file.read(8192)
        all_data += data
        if not data:
            break
        size += len(data)

        saved_file=open('upload_path', 'wb') 
        saved_file.write(all_data) 
        saved_file.close()

    MySQLcursor.execute("insert into ImagePathDatabase (path) values ('" + MySQLdb.escape_string(myFile.filename) + "')")
    MySQLcursor.execute("commit;")
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Andrew

Comment: how to get file from http post and read file in any function in cherrypy

Comment: Well you could add [if cherrypy.request.method == 'POST':].  What do you mean by read file in any function?

Comment: read file mean here how parse file name here or how to get name of file

Comment: Oh it's myFile.filename.  It's in the sql statment.